# IntelliJ: Auto-wrapping only for comments?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to enable auto-wrapping only for comments? So far I only found the setting to enable auto-wrapping for everything.

Comment: Do you mean reformatting code or soft wrapping in the editor?

Comment: Both were best but either would do the trick for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javadoc comments are covered by

`Editor > Code Style > Java > JavaDoc > Wrap at right margin`

(So called) single line comments such as ...

```
// this is a comment
```

... are another matter. There's no configuration item available in `Editor > Code Style > <your_langauage> > Wrapping and Braces` to control these.

**Edit 1**: based on your first reply to this answer: "I am looking for auto-wrapping only for JavaDoc."

- Untick this item: `Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Ensure right margin is not exceeded`
- Tick this item: `Editor > Code Style > Java > JavaDoc > Wrap at right margin`

Here's a pair of screenshots showing before and after formatting, with the above configuration in place:

- Before
  [image]
- After
  [image]

The IntelliJ formatter has not wrapped the code (because `Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Ensure right margin is not exceeded` is not ticked) but it has wrapped the Javaodc (because `Editor > Code Style > Java > JavaDoc > Wrap at right margin` is ticked).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your solution also wraps source code. I am looking for auto-wrapping only for JavaDoc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is what I was looking for :-) Cheers!

Comment: This does not seem to work for me... When I select "Code > Reformat code", comments are wrapped but the code too...

Answer (score 1):

### IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 - Wrap JavaDoc only

```
Settings > Editor > Cody Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces
```

- **Hard wrap at:** [Your preferred value for JavaDoc wrapping]
- **Wrap on typing:** No
- **Keep when reformatting > Ensure right margin is not exceeded:** Disabled
- If any setting here is set to **Wrap if long** or **Chop down if long**, then change it to **Do not wrap**.

```
Settings > Editor > Cody Style > Java > JavaDoc
```

- **Other > Wrap at right margin:** Enabled

Unfortunately, you cannot use "Wrap on typing" for JavaDoc only, because it will wrap code too, even if code wrapping is completely disabled.

Use CTRL+ALT+L to wrap your JavaDoc (Reformat Code).

---

[Settings > Editor > Cody Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtt0C.png)
[Settings > Editor > Cody Style > Java > JavaDoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2vsQ.png)